# How to get azure token using c# client?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, asp.net-core, postman

I am trying to get all vm size name from my Azure account and I am using [This approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list#code-try-0)
In site when I click try out I am getting back result which I need.

Json look like:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "Standard_D1_v2",
      "numberOfCores": 1,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 51200,
      "memoryInMB": 3584,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Standard_D2_v2",
      "numberOfCores": 2,
      "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
      "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 102400,
      "memoryInMB": 7168,
      "maxDataDiskCount": 8
    },
}
```

And after logged in microsoft gets token and request looks like:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/North%20Europe/vmSizes?api-version=2019-12-01
Authorization: Bearer {{token.....}}
```

I need to get token for making request which I don't know,
I have credentials like:

azure_client_id
 azure_client_secret
 azure_tenant_id
 azure_subscription_id

Using this credentials how can I achieve this json result, in short how can I get token.

Tried approaches:

[This one](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/getting-an-azure-access-token-for-a-web-application-entirely-in-code/) [Read this but no info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) [investigated also this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) 
 [also this question in stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930835/programmatically-getting-the-list-of-azure-virtual-machine-sizes)

P.S. I am using aspnet core 3.1 web app maybe it is better client for azure. I used ComputeClient but no success. In final I thought using httpclient but first of all I need to test with postman.

Comment: Check out my article on testing with Postman, you can skip to the part where authentication is configured with client credentials: https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-2-postman You will need to use `https://management.azure.com/.default` as the scope though.

Comment: @juunas thanks a lot but I would like implement some another logic with c# postman it is just for testing, I updated my question header as well. And I have only for credentials I dont have scope which throws exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure resource with a service principal, we need to assign [Azure RABC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) to the service principal, such as Contributor.

For example

1. Create service principal and assign Azure RABC role to it. Since you want to list Azure VM size, we can use the role Virtual Machine Contributor.

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric" --role "Virtual Machine Contributor"
```

[image]

2. Get token

```
POST /<your AD tenant domain>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<>
&client_secret=<>
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
```

3. List Azure VM size

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/eastus/vmSizes?api-version=2019-12-01
Authorization: Bearer {{token.....}}
```

[image]

4. .Net Core With Azure Net SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent`

```
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                      clientId, // the sp appId
                      clientSecret, // the sp password
                      tenantId, // the sp tenant  
                       AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                   .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                   .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                   .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                   .Build();
            ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(restClient);
            client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;// the subscription you use

           var vmSizes= await client.VirtualMachineSizes.ListAsync("eastus");
            foreach (var vmSize in vmSizes) {

                Console.WriteLine("The VM Size Name : "+ vmSize.Name);


            }
```

[image]